# How to draw shape layer on Imageview from masked image

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to draw custom shapes on imageview based on the masked image

After processing the image I am getting masked imaged as follows

Original image[image]

Masked image after image processing
[image]

How can I draw shape from masked image? (For red area)

I tried creating shape layer with masked image but it's not working

```
let myLayer = CAShapeLayer()
myLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
let myImage = maskImage?.cgImage
myLayer.frame = self.imageView.bounds
myLayer.contents = myImage
self.imageView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
```

Now I am thinking to get a UIBezierPath from masked image (red area) but I am not sure how.